# Is 20K reputation required for wiki tag approvals for new sites

Tags: discussion, support, reputation, community-wiki

I am one of the zeitgeist developers and I spend a lot of time helping people with problems and misconceptions.

I had an idea of creating a wiki on askubuntu for the `zeitgeist` tag. When I opened the [tag info page](https://askubuntu.com/tags/zeitgeist/info) I see this message

```
Tag wikis can be edited by users with more than 20000 reputation.
```

What does this mean? Approval of changes to tag wiki page? I can write the wiki but if it has to approved by someone of rep 20K then I don't think it is feasible.

Now the issue is no one has 20K reputations on askubuntu (as of now). The user with highest rep is [Oli](https://askubuntu.com/users/449/oli) who has 18.3K but still that is far from 20K

So in this case, what would new sites do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This means users with 20k rep **do not have to have their tag wiki edits approved by *other users***.

Everyone else has to be approved.

See the [/faq](https://askubuntu.com/faq) for the list of reputation required to approve edits and tag edits.

Answer (score 2):

I've gotten a few tag wiki edit requests from low rep users adding tag wikis so I think it just goes into the edit pool.

Thanks for helping with [zeitgeist](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/zeitgeist) Manish, it's always great when an upstream project participates!